# MySQL Bash for loops

Tags: bash, mysql

[image: MySQL_Query_Table]

I have a bunch of directories created as per "lesson column"

example:

```
/tmp/Caldera/ 
/tmp/Basic Navigation/
/tmp/Signs and Symbols/
```

I have a bunch of json files example:

```
0e689686-4f5a-4800-90ac-771cfe228532.json
bb6632cc-633a-4cc9-9188-1407d7c9cf38.json
1a9e620f-253a-44ee-a68d-11fb7fe8d082.json
```

These above files need to land up in their directory:

```
0e689686-4f5a-4800-90ac-771cfe228532.json ---> /tmp/Caldera/
bb6632cc-633a-4cc9-9188-1407d7c9cf38.json ---> /tmp/Basic Navigation/
1a9e620f-253a-44ee-a68d-11fb7fe8d082.json ---> /tmp/Signs and Symbols/
```

I was going to use a variable called "INFO" to pull this query from SQL.

```
echo "$INFO" | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

then add an extension onto the end of the file ".json" to look like `"0e689686-4f5a-4800-90ac-771cfe228532.json"`, finally move the file from the source directory into `/tmp/Caldera/` only.

Same for `bb6632cc-633a-4cc9-9188-1407d7c9cf38.json ---> /tmp/Basic Navigation/` only.

I think I would need to use a for loop, something like:

```
INFO=$( /usr/bin/mysql -s 
--password=$MYSQL_PASSWORD 
--user=$MYSQL_USER 
--host=$MYSQL_HOST 
--database=$MYSQL_DB 
--disable-column-names 
--execute="SELECT 
    cl.uuid AS compiled_lessons_uuid,
    cl.videos_uuid, 
    cl.assessments_uuid,
    cl.lessons_uuid, 
    les.name AS lesson 
FROM 
    compiled_lessons cl 
JOIN 
    lessons les 
ON 
    les.uuid = cl.lessons_uuid;" )

SOURCE_DIR="/opt/assessments/

for line in $( cat echo "$INFO" | awk '{ print $3.json }' ) ; do

    mv "$SOURCE_DIR"/$line /tmp/{lesson}/

done
```

lesson is referring to `{lesson}` column in the pic attached. example `/tmp/Caldera` as above.

Somehow bash should check `$3` and move it into `$5`. That is the real question here.

Any idea on how to do this.

Comment: format your question and show your `$INFO` and `$SOURCE_DIR` variables values. Also, what is `{lesson}`?

Comment: There's an unclosed quoted string on the `SOURCE_DIR=` line. Also, `cat echo "$INFO"` will try to concatenate the files `echo` and `/usr/bin/mysql`. This is probably not what you intended. Why do you get all that data with the query when you only want a single column?